# In Razor Pages, how do I correctly use the asp-for tag helper with an object?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following PageModel:

```
public class EmailSettingsModel : AuthorizedPageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public EmailSettingsModel mdl { get; set; }


    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}


public class EmailSettingsViewModel
{
    public string IfrToAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and then the following CSHMTL snippet:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label font-weight-bold">To: Address</label>
    <input asp-for="mdl.IfrToAddress" class="form-control mb-1">
    <small class="text-muted">Can be more than one address, but MUST be seperated by a semi-colon (;) between each address.</small>
</div>
```

What I don't understand is why the IfrToAddress property won't compile.

I wanted to separate my PageModel and the ViewModel into separate classes so that my page model wouldn't be clogged up with properties up top. But this code doesn't compile with the notation I have the CSHTML.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What error messages are you getting?

Comment: AND.... it's working now... I am using ReSharper and I think it was getting in the way!